# How does one pronounce Pompey?

Tags: pronunciation, names

Gnaeus Pompeius Magnus, a general during the last years of the Republic:

Some folks are under the impression that the standard English version of his name, Pompey, is pronounced "POM-pee," even though the Anglicized Latin variant is "pom-PAY-us," with the stress on the second syllable.

I was under that same impression as well.

Recently, though, I watched the somewhat silly yet entertaining HBO series titled, simply, *Rome,* in which various characters refer to and address the brave general as "POM-pay."

What gives?

Here's where it's happening in the TV show (one of many instances) - courtesy of @tchrist:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1rMWzzAl_o&ab_channel=BayA

Comment: You can hear that happening [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1rMWzzAl_o).

Comment: Please show some referenced/attributed research rather than just anecdotal evidence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Done.

Comment: The M-W article is important; M-W is a respected authority.

Answer (score 10):

Both OED and Merriam-Webster agree that the second syllable is "-ee", and the first (stressed) syllable has the LOT vowel:

[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/265416) (£)

> Pronunciation:  Brit. pronunciation/ˈpɒmpi/ , U.S. pronunciation/ˈpɑmpi/

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Pompey)

> Pom·​pey ˈpäm-pē

There's a long tradition in English Classicism of pronouncing the ancients' names almost without regard to how they might or might not have been pronounced in their own time - eg "Cicero" with not just one but *two* /s/s, "Julius" with a /dʒ/, and so on. I have never heard anything other than "ee" used at the end, but I guess what HBO do is up to them... I would have thought they'd go for "Pompayus" if they wanted to seem clever, though.

Comment: I suspect the HBO pronunciation is just confused ignoramuses conflating Pompey with the town of Pompeii.

Comment: @TonyK Well that’s liable to blow up in their faces, isn’t it?

Comment: Don't forget _Don Juan_.

Comment: Also, the diminuitive-like shortening of names is somewhat common: Livy and Tully for Titus Livius and Marcu Tullius Cicero, for example.

Comment: @chepner Don't forget the way English speakers use the Roman letter "R" in *Cicero* for something utterly unrelated to what actual Romans used their own letter for.

Comment: @tchrist I do forget that sometimes, as I couldn't pronounce /r/ correctly if my life depended on it :)

Comment: As a Native American English speaker I have always heard the pronunciation "pom-PAY", including and especially from my Latin teacher in school. I always considered "POM-pee" a British-ism.

Comment: @shadowtalker interesting. One expects Latin teachers to be particular sticklers for whatever *they* were taught was 'correct', so that speaks to an established tradition.

Comment: @AakashM: I think Latin teachers often pronounce these kinds of names based on the spelling-to-sound rules they have learned for pronouncing *Latin.* So I'm not sure there's more of an established tradition than "Pompeius is pronounced in an average 'restored' anglicized pronuniciation of Latin as 'pom-PAY-oos'/'pom-PAY-us'", with *Pompey* then being interpreted by speakers who say  "pom-PAY" as just a truncation of *Pompeius*